# JMeter on RHEL4

Tags: redhat, java, jmeter

Downloaded JMeter to do some testing, but trying to run it I get teh following errors

```
[oracle@ripple jakarta-jmeter-2.5]$ bin/jmeter
Warning: -server not understood. Ignoring.
Warning: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError not understood. Ignoring.
Warning: -Xms512m not understood. Ignoring.
Warning: -Xmx512m not understood. Ignoring.
Warning: -XX:NewSize=128m not understood. Ignoring.
Warning: -XX:MaxNewSize=128m not understood. Ignoring.
Warning: -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2 not understood. Ignoring.
Warning: -XX:PermSize=64m not understood. Ignoring.
Warning: -XX:MaxPermSize=64m not understood. Ignoring.
Warning: -jar not understood. Ignoring.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bin.ApacheJMeter.jar
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.FirstThread.run() (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_ThreadRun(java.lang.Thread) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at _Jv_RunMain(java.lang.Class, byte const, int, byte const, boolean) (/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.5.0.0)
   at __gcj_personality_v0 (/home/oracle/jakarta-jmeter-2.5/java.version=1.4.2)
   at __libc_start_main (/lib64/tls/libc-2.3.4.so)
   at _Jv_RegisterClasses (/home/oracle/jakarta-jmeter-2.5/java.version=1.4.2)
```

Java is installed and functional (This server runs an Oracle IAS server). How do I get JMeter to work?

Running RHEL 4 update 5, Java version is 1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download and install Java 1.6 SDK from Oracle site. GNU implementation of Java (GNU GCJ) can't handle startup parameters as you can see.